# How do I make VS2008 open Compact Framework forms using CF winforms designer

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, designer

I have a problem with opening CF.NET forms using VSTS 2008. It uses the regular windows forms designer instead of the smart device one.

Everything was fine under VS2008 Pro, but after installing VSTS this seems broken. Is it possible to modify this behaviour somewhere in the settings or should I blame this on a broken install and reinstall VS?

Comment: Is this a problem with one specific project. or even new Smart Device projects?

Comment: Even new Smart Device projects. It's quite bizarre really - even the default Form1.cs opens up with default Vista skin instead of the WinMo one.

Comment: The environment I get this on is VSTS 2008 Team Suite (both with and without SP1) on Vista.

Comment: Just to make it more clear - it's not only a case of wrong skin, but even the code generated in Form1.designer.cs is not CF compatible (like new MainMenu(components) instead of new MainMenu())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it or not, someone else encountered the exact same problem AND found the solution!

The full solution is [here](http://www.nullify.net/Article/287.aspx), but in short, you need to run the following registry fix and the designer is back :)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETCompactFramework\v3.5.0.0\PocketPC\AsmmetaBinder]
"TypeName"="Microsoft.CompactFramework.Build.PocketPC.BindingService, Microsoft.CompactFramework.Build.Tasks, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, Custom=null"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETCompactFramework\v3.5.0.0\PocketPC\AsmmetaBinder\4118C335-430C-497f-BE48-11C3316B135E]
"TypeName"="Microsoft.CompactFramework.Build.WM50PocketPC.BindingService, Microsoft.CompactFramework.Build.Tasks, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, Custom=null"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETCompactFramework\v3.5.0.0\Smartphone\AsmmetaBinder]
"TypeName"="Microsoft.CompactFramework.Build.SmartPhone.BindingService, Microsoft.CompactFramework.Build.Tasks, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, Custom=null"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETCompactFramework\v3.5.0.0\Smartphone\AsmmetaBinder\BD0CC567-F6FD-4ca3-99D2-063EFDFC0A39]
"TypeName"="Microsoft.CompactFramework.Build.WM50SmartPhone.BindingService, Microsoft.CompactFramework.Build.Tasks, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, Custom=null"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETCompactFramework\v3.5.0.0\WindowsCE\AsmmetaBinder]
"TypeName"="Microsoft.CompactFramework.Build.WindowsCE.BindingService, Microsoft.CompactFramework.Build.Tasks, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, Custom=null"
```

Answer (score 0):

Under Tools >> Options >> Device Tools >> General, is "Show skin" in Windows Forms Designer checked?

When you open the form, is the "FormFactor" property set to a windows mobile style form?

Comment: The checkbox is checked. The FormFactory property is actually missing from the properties box of the Form :(